# Is performing namaz mandatory in order to go to heaven?

Tags: salat, jannah, akhirah

My 20 years brother died without much knowledge about Islam and he was not doing namaz (salah). However, he was very kind, helpful and good human being. What will happen to him? Will he be punished by God?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Surah Al Asar(https://quran.com/103/3?translations=20) the basic requirements for successfully entring jannah are:
1. To have Faith  means to be muslim
2. Good Deeds
3. Keep reminding each other of Akhirah
4. Have patience in this life as it is a test

These 4 things are required to pass the test of life. 
As for salah, it is very important part of Muslim's faith. But its one of the good deeds as mentioned in 2 point. It is a fard. And its Allahs right that he can forgive someone who do not preform salah. Allah will forgive every sin except shirk. Allah will not forgive a human right util the human forgives it. And salah is not a human right its totally Allah's. He may punish for it or forgive it. But as for you brother he was a Muslim he will InshaAllah go to Jannah finally. You should pray for your brother that Allah may forgive your brother for not preforming salah.
May Allah forgive us all.

Comment: Please pray for my brother. Allah mere bhai (Arif Shaikh) ki magfirat kar de aameen summa aameen.

Comment: He was not only my brother. He was my everything I can't stop myself by crying every time and every second. Why Allah called my brother so early? Why Allah didn't call me he was very young.

Comment: Will Allah take tough examinations for 20 years sink?

Comment: The age of early 20 comes under child?

Comment: @FirozaShaikh: I am really sorry for your loss. This phase is very tough. There are certain things you can do when your loved one dies:  
1. Pray for them that they may pass next life without any difficulty
2. Allah's messenger lost his family but he stayed very patient. as i told in the ayah above we have to be patient. you must remember that this is a temporary life and IA you will meet him in a better place after this life soon. its just everyone spends his/her given time here and goes again in front of Allah. In Janah you will meet all your loved ones

Comment: @FirozaShaikh : 
You might wanna watch this video: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98e-lm6wLj4&t=3s) ... it explains more in detail. May Allah give you patience and peace. JazakAllah

Comment: We never complaint and demanded for anything to Allah whatever Allah gave to us we were happy but why such thing happen to my little brother. He was very nice human being. He was deserving better in life and Allah didn't gave one chance to him for living with us.

Comment: JazakAllah zeeshan but I feel Allah is very much angry on me. In life whenever I start to feel happy then suddenly Allah take away all my happiness and give me sorrow and sorrow only and this time Allah has taken my everything. I think Allah doesn't like me. Allah hate me a lot. Allah doesn't want to make me happy.

Comment: As i told realier this life is temporay. I might have better plan for him in next life.   
About Allah being angry: The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) is reported to have said: “Verily, if Allah loves a people, He makes them go through trials. Whoever is satisfied, for him is contentment, and whoever is angry upon him is wrath.” (Hadith-Tirmidhi)

Comment: Shukriya brother. as you said Allah has better plan for him in next life Insha Allah it should happen Ameen summa ameen. Please pray for my brother(Arif shaikh). Allah Arif ki magfirat kar de Ameen.

Comment: One last question Zeeshan I will be very happy if u will give the answer of this question. People say Allah call good people early.   Was my brother very good thats way Allah called him so early?

Comment: People say if u will love Allah and pray then Allah will solve your all problem then how come Allah takes trail of those people who is close to Allah and continuously giving them pain.

Comment: @FirozaShaikh: Think of it in terms of Allah love his prophet Muhammad (PBUH)  the most from all of his creation and yet prophet of Allah had to face many difficult tests. Same goes for Phrophet Ibraheem (PBUH) he was called "Khaleel Allah" means very close friend of Allah and yet we see he had to face trials as well. Even in his last age when he had the vision to sacrifice his only child. Quran is full of examples like these where Allah give trials to the ones he love. As a test to how much they love him. And to give them more high places in Janah. As that is the ultimate prize.

Comment: @FirozaShaikh: Allah says in Quran "Every soul will taste death, and you will only be given your [full] compensation on the Day of Resurrection. So he who is drawn away from the Fire and admitted to Paradise has attained [his desire]. And what is the life of this world except the enjoyment of delusion." Surah Al e 'Imran [3:185]

Comment: So this life is a mere delusion. Its like a rest station in middle of a journey. Some people leave early from this station and some leave a bit late. But the truth is everyone will leave and our destinations are either hell or heaven. So it doesn't matter who goes first or last.